# Uexpected Function Behavior. JS Classes

Tags: javascript

I've created HTML builder (finally!) 
It just has methods: *create div, span, p, br.* 
As you can see in console.logs it has nesting and chaining behavior. 
And for detecting nesting and chaining I have *item instanceof Class* 
But it doesn't show me correct return when I have nesting condition. 
Need help to find the mistake and get output in first console.log =

```
<div><p>Hello</p><p>World</p></div>
```

```js
class Templater {
    constructor() {
        this.arr = []; 
        this.nesting = false;
    }
    transform(tags) {
        return tags.join("");
    }

    div(...tags) {
       tags.forEach(item => {
            this.nesting = (item instanceof Templater);
        });
        this.arr.push(`<div>${this.transform(tags)}</div>`) 
        return this;
    }

    span(...tags) {
        tags.forEach(item => {
            this.nesting = (item instanceof Templater);
        });
        this.arr.push(`<span>${this.transform(tags)}</span>`);
        return this
    }
    br(argument) {
        tags.forEach(item => {
            this.nesting = (item instanceof Templater);
        });
        if (argument) {
            throw new Error('Nested content is not allowed');
        } else {
            this.arr.push(`<br>`);
           
            return this; 
        }
    }
    p(...tags) {
        tags.forEach(item => {
            this.nesting = (item instanceof Templater);
        });
        this.arr.push(`<p>${this.transform(tags)}</p>`);
        return this
    }

    toString() {
        if (this.nesting) {
            this.nesting = false; 
            let qwe = [...this.arr]; 
            this.arr = []; 
            return qwe[qwe.length-1];
        } else {
            let qwe = [...this.arr]; 
            this.arr = [];
           return qwe.join('');
        }
    }

}
const template = new Templater();

console.log(template.div(
    template.p('Hello'),
    template.p('World')
).toString());

console.log(template.div().toString());
console.log(template.div('Hello').p('fix').toString());
```

Comment: Your 2 requirements are at odds with one another 1) Supporting chaining 2) supporting nesting.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me with :

```
    console.log(template.div(
        template.p('Hello').p('World').toString()
    ).toString());
```

Comment: The OP's question was about finding a mistake. Can you please add an explanation about why this might work? It will make the answer stronger and provide better help for others in the future.

Comment: This works, the nesting example does not.